# Extension of mail file setup by POP and IMAP irrespective of OS and Mail Clients

Tags: operating-systems, imap, email-client, pop3

In case of Windows 10, I found extension of mail file setup by POP is PST and setup by IMAP is OST.

Would you like to let us know..

- What will be mail file extensions for other OS like MacBook and Linux (e.g. Ubuntu)?
- What will be mail file extensions for other mail clients like Windows Thunderbird, Apple Mail, Ubuntu Thunderbird, Hiri, Geary, etc?
- Moreover, in case of Windows, there are two separate files for POP and IMAP. What about other OS?

With Regards
eGoal

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Data Files PST (Personal Storage Table) is Microsoft open **proprietary** file format used for Microsoft Outlook, Windows Messaging, and Microsoft Exchange Client.

Outlook Data Files OST (Offline Storage Table) is Microsoft offline format, unlike PST file, which depends upon account configuration and therefore cannot be opened individually.

In other words, PST is a copy of emails, calendars, contacts that can be accessed. OST is a backup of the items to be synced with the email server when the user is offline.